# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) *about global variables

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I have a problem with compiling my files.
I compiled and got this message

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_airport_label", referenced from:
  FlightMap::pathfind_before(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,             
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
  FlightMap::pathfind(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,  
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
"_dijkstra", referenced from:
  FlightMap::findShortestRoute(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
  FlightMap::pathfind_before(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
  FlightMap::fun_dijkstra(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
 (maybe you meant: __ZN9FlightMap12fun_dijkstraERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE)
"_distance_label", referenced from:
  FlightMap::pathfind_before(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
  FlightMap::pathfind(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
"_path", referenced from:
FlightMap::pathfind(std::__1::basic_string<char, 
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, 
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FlightMap-9a7ab0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

I think there are some problems in global variable in FlightMap.h file.
(I edited Flight.h -> FlightMap.h)
I declared 4 global variables like

```
stack<string> path;
map<string, string > airport_label;
map<double, string > distance_label;
map<string, double > dijkstra;
```

I have already tried to put "extern" in front of each global variable but it does not work.

In FlightMap.h file code(Edited Flight.h -> FlightMap.h)

```
#ifndef LAB6_FLIGHTMAP_H
#define LAB6_FLIGHTMAP_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include "AdjacencyListDirectedGraph.h"

 extern stack<string> path;
 extern map<string, string > airport_label;
 extern map<double, string > distance_label;
 extern map<string, double > dijkstra;
 .
 .
 .
```

Also, those global variables are used in FlightMap.cpp file.(I edited!)

I think that is where problems occur

Comment: How do you compille it? Is `Flight.cpp` or `Flight.o` included on the commandline?

Comment: Also, please choose one of g++ or clang (or none, since this is not really about a particular compiler).

Comment: I tried to g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall %s FlightMap.cpp %s -o %s but error says clang:error...

Comment: First and foremost you got this error not when compiling but when linking. This is quite important detail to understand your issue.

Comment: Do you try just to compile FlightMap.cpp into object file? Then you are missing `-c` parameter. Without it clang or gcc tries to build the executable

Comment: Any number of references will tell you how to declare and define global variables correctly. The important point is that you **declare** them in Flight.h using `extern` and also **define** them in Flight.cpp without using `extern`. You need to do **both**. It's not hard but not something that you are likely to get right by guessing.

Comment: @john Wow I resolved the problem. I declared global variables using extern in FlightMap.h and also declared without extern in FlightMap.cpp. May i get some explanation why I could resolve errors?

Comment: You **declared** with `extern`, but **defined** without. Every variable / function needs exactly one definition (but can hany any number of declarations, including zero, as long as those match each other).

Comment: @rocketsssss You have to understand the difference between declarations and definitions. With `extern` it's a declaration, without it a definition. Your global variable need to be defined exactly once. So you put the definition in one cpp file. But your globals can be declared as many times as you like, so you put the declarations in a header file where they can be included many times without getting multiple definition errors. All the compiler needs to see to generate code is a declaration, but the linker needs to see exactly one definition to link the program.

Comment: @rocketsssss  So the above method keeps the compiler and the linker happy.

Answer (score 1):

Use fully qualified names in your header file's declarations:

```
#ifndef LAB6_FLIGHTMAP_H
#define LAB6_FLIGHTMAP_H

//#includes ...

extern std::stack<std::string> path;
extern std::map<std::string, std::string> airport_label;
extern std::map<double, std::string> distance_label;
extern std::map<std::string, double> dijkstra;
...
#endif
```

And in `FlightMap.cpp` you need to define these global variabes:

```
std::stack<std::string> path;
std::map<std::string, std::string> airport_label;
std::map<double, std::string> distance_label;
std::map<std::string, double> dijkstra;
```

`extern` tells the compiler that the variable *will* be defined somewhere, in another translation unit, and leaves resolving this up to the linker. The linker now has to find the definition in any of the compiled files, but can't since there is no definition anywhere. By actually putting the definition (that is, without `extern`) in one file (and one file only), the linker will be happy.

Comment: Thank you for your teaching!  I have a quick question. As I know, extern is used when I declared some global variables in a "source file" and used in another "source file." But, in this situation, I declared global variables in FlightMap.h and used them in FlightMap.cpp. Even though this situation, should I use "extern" keyword?

Comment: `extern` is typically used in a `.h` or `.hpp` file that is supposed to be used by more than one `.cpp` file - or if the variables themselves are referenced in the header fille. The variables that are declared that way can then be used in all `.cpp` files that includes that `.h`/`.hpp` file. Only _one_ `.cpp` should actually define the variables though.